# ALPR provider for Xillinx

Tags: xilinx, lpr, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I'm looking into doing some ALPR(Automatic License Plate Recognition) project and I see that some ALPR providers supports Raspherry Pi and Jetson devices. Does any support Xilinx

Answer (score 0):

I found that Plate Recognizer supports Xilinx Zynz boards. Go [here](https://platerecognizer.com/blog/alpr-for-xilinx-zynq/) to read more about setting it up for your ALPR project.